# Trying to grab XML file after Google Maps Query

Tags: xml, delphi, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to grab the XML file results after using a Google Maps API query, but my Delphi app is throwing a "IOHandler value is not valid." error.  The "IdHTTP1.Get" line appears to be the culprit, but why?

My goal is to get the latitude and longitude coordinates from the results of the query and post them to a database.  Here's my code that's producing the error.

```
 procedure TViewMaps.GetXMLBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    lat, lng: String;
    xml: IXMLDocument;
    s: TStream;
begin
  // Create XML File to hard disk
  s := TFileStream.Create('mydata.xml', fmCreate);
    try
      IdHTTP1.Get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=MyKey',s);
      xml := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
             {xml.LoadFromXML(sName),  at: xml.ChildNodes.FindNode = ('result') ChildNodes.FindNode ('formatted_address . ');  }

      // Load XML file for data display
      XMLDocument1.LoadFromFile('mydata.xml');
      XMLDocument1.Active := True;

        //lat := XMLDocument1.DocumentElement;

    finally
      XMLDocument1.Active := False;
      s.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: what version of Delphi/Indyare you using? In older versions, you must create an SSL IOHandler yourself. Also, don't forget to include the OpenSSL libraries.

Comment: @whosrdaddy - Delphi XE6 with Indy 10.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "not valid" error means an HTTPS request is being made but an SSL component has not been assigned to the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property, such as `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`.  Also see [New HTTPS functionality for TIdHTTP](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20141222.aspx).